# R ggplot2 grid labeling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been asked to make a bar plot from pollution data. Example data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hb7gd18vyvls64i/data.csv?dl=0). Data structure is as follows

```
    str(datos) 'data.frame':    55 obs. of  10 variables:   
$ PROVINCIA    : int  46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 ...   
$ ESTACION     : Factor w/ 55 levels "Alacant-El_Pla",..: 5 1 2 3 8 23 24 21 31 22 ...   
$ MAXIMO_HORARIO    : num  99.5 88.5 88.5 90 97.5 87.3 96 92.5 88 20 ... 
$ PROMEDIO_DIARIO     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...   
$ MAXIMO_OCTOHORARIO  : num  103.9 83.1 80.9 75.7 95.1 ...   
$ VARIACION_MAX_HOR   : num  -25.2 -6.5 -6.7 -1.2 -13.2 -15.4 -12.7
    -29.5 -16.3 NA ...   
$ VARIACION_PRM_DIA   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...   
$ OSCILACION_DIARIO   : num  16.5 63.7 53.3 62 26.8 31.3 29.2 15 52 20 ...   
$ ESTACIONALIDAD_MAX  : num  -38.2 -39.6 -36.8 -38.8 -37.6 -51.8 -35.6 -40.3 -42.9 -86.5 ...   
$ ESTACIONALIDAD_MAX-1: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I've tried to use ggplot2 geom_bar geometry and facetting with the following code

```
datos=read.csv("data.csv",header=T,sep=",", na.strings="-99.9")

ggplot(datos, aes(ESTACION,MAXIMO_HORARIO, fill = factor(MAXIMO_HORARIO))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, size=10)) +
  facet_grid(PROVINCIA ~ .)
```

obtaining this output

[image]

This is on the right way but I would like that every facet (group) shows its own values and not empty space that correspond to data in another facet, and also with the right labels in each grid. I can split data into three parts and produce three different plots but I'd like to build just a single file with the three plots in it.

Desired output would look like
[image]

EDIT: Output of dput(datos)
**>

```
dput(datos)
structure(list(PROVINCIA = c(46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ESTACION = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
8L, 23L, 24L, 21L, 31L, 22L, 41L, 27L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
18L, 28L, 29L, 19L, 37L, 39L, 26L, 49L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 4L, 
7L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 17L, 20L, 33L, 25L, 30L, 32L, 36L, 35L, 
34L, 38L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 50L, 51L, 40L), .Label = c("Alacant-El_Pla", 
"Alacant-Florida_Babel", "Alacant-Rabassa", "Albalat_dels_Tarongers", 
"Alcoi-Verge_dels_Lliris", "Algar_de_Pal", "Alzira", "Benidorm", 
"Benig", "Bull", "Burjassot-Facultats", "Burriana", "Castell1", 
"Castell2", "Castell3", "Castell4", "Caudete_de_las_Fuentes", 
"Cirat", "Coratxar", "Cortes_de_Pall", "Elda-Lacy", "El_Pin", 
"Elx-Agroalimentari", "Elx-Parc_de_Bombers", "Gandia", "La_Vall_d", 
"Lluce", "Morella", "Onda", "Ontinyent", "Orihuela", "Paterna-CEAM", 
"Quart_de_Poblet", "Sagunt-CEA", "Sagunt-Nord", "Sagunt-Port", 
"Sant_Jordi", "Torrebaja", "Torre_Endom", "Torrent-El_Vedat", 
"Torrevieja", "Val1", "Val2", "Val3", "Val4", "Val5", "Val6", 
"Val7", "Vilafranca", "Vilamarxant", "Villar_del_Arzobispo", 
"Vinaros", "VinarosP", "Viver", "Zorita"), class = "factor"), 
    MAXIMO_HORARIO = c(99.5, 88.5, 88.5, 90, 97.5, 87.3, 96, 
    92.5, 88, 20, 20, 81.5, 99, 91.7, 93.5, 81.5, 90.5, 84.5, 
    100.3, 96.3, 41.7, 91.5, 57.3, NA, 93, 111.5, 86.8, NA, 100.3, 
    21.9, 80.5, 111, 98.7, 87.3, 89.7, 87.5, 41.7, 81.7, NA, 
    20, 84.8, 92, 88.7, NA, 74, NA, 95, 20.5, 85.7, 80, 82.3, 
    76, 20, 90.8, NA), PROMEDIO_DIARIO = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), MAXIMO_OCTOHORARIO = c(103.9, 83.1, 
    80.9, 75.7, 95.1, 82.9, 90.2, 83.5, 85, NA, NA, 77.1, 76.7, 
    91.4, 73.1, 65.1, 96.6, 81.1, 110.5, 91.1, NA, 87.8, 54.8, 
    NA, 95.1, 116.8, 79.9, NA, 107.2, 73.9, 70.5, 102.8, 100.5, 
    77.5, 80.9, 86.9, NA, 70.5, NA, NA, 73.5, 86.9, 86, NA, 83.5, 
    NA, 84.5, 20.5, 90.8, 71.5, 67.5, 64.5, NA, 91.4, NA), VARIACION_MAX_HOR = c(-25.2, 
    -6.5, -6.7, -1.2, -13.2, -15.4, -12.7, -29.5, -16.3, NA, 
    NA, -32.5, -11.5, -22.3, -19.5, -22.3, -25.3, -24.7, -14.7, 
    -18, NA, -12.8, -36, NA, -27.3, -11.4, -15.7, NA, -21.4, 
    -103.6, -26, -24.5, -33.1, -30, -31, -17.8, NA, -15.1, NA, 
    NA, -23.5, -32.5, -16.1, NA, -32.3, NA, -28.2, 0.3, -30.5, 
    -17.3, -18.4, -19.7, NA, -31.2, NA), VARIACION_PRM_DIA = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), OSCILACION_DIARIO = c(16.5, 
    63.7, 53.3, 62, 26.8, 31.3, 29.2, 15, 52, 20, 20, 51.8, 85.7, 
    27.5, 80, 74.8, 45, 48.3, 12.5, 21.6, 41.7, 41.8, 35.3, NA, 
    26.5, 27.1, 64.2, NA, 58.6, 3.9, 39.2, 39.3, 32.9, 22.6, 
    43.4, 17.3, 41.7, 46.9, NA, 20, 50.8, 58.2, 64.5, NA, 2.7, 
    NA, 40.2, 1.5, 25.9, 30.5, 58.6, 31, 20, 15.8, NA), ESTACIONALIDAD_MAX = c(-38.2, 
    -39.6, -36.8, -38.8, -37.6, -51.8, -35.6, -40.3, -42.9, -86.5, 
    -83.6, -50.6, -35, -46.8, -45, -57.1, -31.4, -49.7, -35.5, 
    -45.7, -75.2, -44.1, -62.6, NA, -48.4, -10.8, -39.3, NA, 
    -38.1, -86.4, -53.7, -16.5, -42.3, -42.2, -38.1, -48.7, -68.2, 
    -45.4, NA, -87.6, -43.8, -44.2, -43.1, NA, -55.5, NA, -33.1, 
    -86.1, -38.3, -44.4, -41.6, -38.2, -85.5, -50.1, NA), ESTACIONALIDAD_MAX.1 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -71.11, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("PROVINCIA", 
"ESTACION", "MAXIMO_HORARIO", "PROMEDIO_DIARIO", "MAXIMO_OCTOHORARIO", 
"VARIACION_MAX_HOR", "VARIACION_PRM_DIA", "OSCILACION_DIARIO", 
"ESTACIONALIDAD_MAX", "ESTACIONALIDAD_MAX.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-55L))
```

**

Comment: The data is not accessible without a dropbox account.

Comment: Sorry @ziggystar, didn't notice. I've added output of dput(datos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want `facet_wrap` rather than `facet_grid`. Try

```
ggplot(datos, aes(ESTACION,MAXIMO_HORARIO, fill = factor(MAXIMO_HORARIO))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, size=10)) +
  facet_wrap(~PROVINCIA , scales="free", ncol=1)
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`facet_grid()` is not designed for what you want.  Making the three plots separately is the right approach.  But with the `gridExtra` package it is easy to combine these plot elements (the `gridExtra` package calls them "grobs") into a single plot or single file.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

#toy data
dat <- data.frame(x=1:20, y=sample(1:20, size=20, replace=T), group=sample(1:3, size=20, replace=T))

#making each "grob"
p1 <- ggplot(subset(dat, group==1), aes(factor(x), y)) + 
         geom_bar(stat='identity')
p2 <- ggplot(subset(dat, group==2), aes(factor(x), y)) + 
         geom_bar(stat='identity')
p3 <- ggplot(subset(dat, group==3), aes(factor(x), y)) + 
         geom_bar(stat='identity')

#combine them into a single stack of plots
pAll <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol=1)
pAll
```

Note for this approach to work, your x-variable in the parent `data.frame` will have to be a string or a numeric, not a factor.  (For numerics, you have to make it a factor after subsetting: that's the only way `ggplot2` will know that you *don't* want to show the gaps where each subset has no data.  For strings, this won't be a problem and the x-axis doesn't need to be a factor at any point.)

Comment: Thanks @curt-f A nice and fully working solution. Unfortunately I just can mark one answer, yours deserve to be the chosen one.